# Storm:java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established

Tags: docker, apache-storm

I have a storm cluster with 1 nimbus node and 3 supervisor node which are running on docker containers on AWS ec2 instances. I had a topology running with the number of workers equal to 3 and it ran perfectly fine. I stopped and removed this container and started a new one. After this, I seem to have the following error in the supervisor logs:

2016-10-03 21:18:22 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 129 to Netty-Client-hostname:6702 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established

I have edited "/etc/hosts" to include the hostname as follows:
IP-address hostname

Yet, the problems seems to persist. Although, the same topology runs perfectly fine with the number of workers set to 1. Any pointers on solving this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the hostname. I changed the hostname to match the DNS name by updating "/etc/hostname" as well as "/etc/hosts" and the rebooted nimbus instance followed by the supervisor instances. This fixed the problem. Hope this helps anyone who is stuck with the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Please check your supervisor log, sometimes you need to redeploy the app because supervisor has not started the topology yet.